# Relationship between the Fisher distance and Kulback Leibler divergence

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

I am reading the 2017 book *"Information geometry"* by Ay, Jost, Lê, Schwachhöfer. The Fisher distance is given by
$$
d^F(\mu, \nu) := \inf_{\gamma} L(\gamma)
$$
for curves $\gamma:[0,1]\to P$ with arclength

$$
L(\gamma) = \int_0^1 \|\dot\gamma\|_{\gamma(t)} dt
$$

where
$\|a\|_\mu = \langle a, a\rangle_\mu$
is induced by the fisher metric.

Now Ay motivates the Kullback Leibler divergence as a generalization of the squared norm, as its derivative are the geodesics with regard to the (e) and (m) connections. So in this sense the connections induce distance functions. But why are these distances reasonable and compatible with the fisher metric, when the fisher metric induces a very unique distance above?

Are these distances related? If I understand correctly, then the fisher distance $d^F$ is induced by the Levi-Cevita connection? Is this connection a member of the alpha connections family?

My understanding of differential geometry is somewhat limited so these questions might be very basic.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bit of a confusion here, since the geodesics of the (e) and (m) connections are not the third derivatives of the KL divergence. Instead, the third derivatives of the KL divergence give the Christoffel symbols for the (e) and (m) connections (depending on which argument is differentiated twice). For these connections, one can then consider geodesics with respect to these connections, which will be curves that satisfy $\nabla^{(e)}_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma =0$ (and similarly for m). One can compute the length of such curves with respect to the Fisher metric. Such curves will always be longer then their Levi-Civita counterparts.

As for a relationship between the KL divergence and distance induced by the KL divergence, the Fisher metric is the second-order Taylor polynomial of the KL divergence. In other words, given a fixed distribution $P(\theta_0)$
$$D_{\mathrm{KL}}[P(\theta_0) \| P(\theta)] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{jk}\Delta\theta^j\Delta\theta^k g_{jk}(\theta_0) + \mathrm{O}(\Delta\theta^3).$$
As a result, we should expect the KL divergence to have comparisons between the *squared* distance with respect to the Fisher metric.

In many cases, it is possible to bound the distance with respect to the Fisher metric from above in terms of the KL divergence, but generally it's not possible to get bounds going the other way. For an example of the former, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437191/upper-bound-on-the-fisher-rao-distance-between-multivariate-gaussian-measures-by) about the symmetrized KL divergence of multivariate normal distributions. A similar bound holds for multinomial distributions (i.e., $d_F(P,Q)^2 \leq C D_{KL}(P||Q))$ where $P$ and $Q$ are two multinomial distributions and $C$ is a positive constant (which I haven't computed carefully). To see why we cannot get a bound going in the opposite direction in this case, note that with respect to the Fisher metric the space of multinomial distributions is the positive orthant of a unit sphere, so the total diameter of the space is bounded. However, if there is an event which has non-zero probability with respect to $P$ but zero probability with respect to $Q$, the KL divergence $D_{KL}(P||Q)=\infty$, but the distance with respect to the Fisher metric is bounded, so we cannot hope to prove a bound going in the other direction.

And finally, if one considers the entire $(\alpha)$-family of connections where the (e) connection is $\alpha=1$ and the (m) connection is $\alpha=-1$, the Levi-Civita connection will correspond to the $\alpha=0$ connection.

Comment: What still confuses me, is that "straight lines" in my mind are supposed to encapsulate the notion of "shortest path". If the other connections result in geodesics ("straight lines"), which are not the shortest path, why are they reasonable definitions of "straight lines"? I.e. if $\nabla^{(e)}_{\dot{\gamma}(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t)) = 0$ does not result in the shortest path, why is it reasonable?

Comment: That’s a great question! When you use a connection which does not preserve the metric like the Levi-Civita connection, the curves which are autoparallel no longer minimize distance. So these are separate concepts and for this reason, some authors choose to call them “(e) autoparallel curves” to emphasize the difference. And generally speaking, the applications of these curves are not related to their lengths.

Comment: For instance, for an exponential family the (e) and (m) connections give a way to induce the duality-flat structure without needing to derive the natural parameters as “preferred coordinates,” which is a bit anathema to most geometers.

Comment: So essentially these connections pull back straight lines in a particular chart and make them straight lines on the manifold (i.e. (m) connections pull back the chart mapping $\sum \mu_i \delta_i \mapsto (\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$ and (e) connections do the same for the dual of function spaces)? That seems a bit contrary to the entire premise of information geometry a la "Respect the space of distributions instead of using the geometry of an arbitrary parameter space of parametrized distributions"

Comment: @FelixB. For a general statistical manifold, the (e) and (m) connections will not be flat, but they turn out to be flat for exponential families. When I first learned information geometry, I definitely found these connections ad hoc and a bit mysterious. But if you look at statistical literature considering exponential families, the natural parameters/sufficient statistics show up everywhere and there are good statistical reasons to consider them. So (I think) the (e) and (m) connections are reasonably well-motivated from a statistical perspective.

Comment: I should add the disclaimer that I am not a statistician, so only started to appreciate the dual connections once I realized that they had interesting applications in differential geometry.